# multiple functions in one file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is this the correct way to split out code to smaller functions?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#create_form").submit(function() {

    ...

    var is_okay = check_values(...);

    ...

    });
});

function check_values() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to split out code to smaller functions?

Not really, since your `check_values` function is now part of the global `window` object.  Leaking objects into the global space is badm, mkay?

Unfortunately there are so many ways that it *could* be done that it's hard to know where to start.

If your code is small it would be best just to leave it all within the closure inside your `$(document).ready()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function check_values() {
        ...
    }

    $("form#create_form").submit(function() {
        ...
        var is_okay = check_values(...);
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is *a* way to split code into smaller functions.

One thing you should watch for is how many functions you assign in the global scope. If you can group your functions under a common global, for example, you will find you have less to worry about (in terms of maintenance and potential name clashes).